# XNA ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled

Tags: c#, xna

relatively new to programming here, and this is my first "large" independent project; it's a platformer game. So when I look at the code and debug it I understand what it's saying and what the error is, the problem is I can't figure out what the solution is...I've tried tons of different things. Here's where I think the error is. In my splash screen class;

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{            
    inputManager.Update();
    Animation a = animation[imageNumber];
    FAnimation.Update(gameTime, ref a);
    animation[imageNumber] = a;

    if (animation[imageNumber].Alpha == 0.0f)
        imageNumber++;

    if (imageNumber >= animation.Count - 1 || inputManager.KeyPressed(Keys.Enter))
    {                    
        ScreenManager.Instance.AddScreen(new TitleScreen(), inputManager);
    }             
}

public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    animation[imageNumber].Draw(spriteBatch); ------> (ERROR)
}
```

and then this is the AddScreen method from my screen manager class;

```
public void AddScreen(GameScreen screen, InputManager inputManager)
{
    transition = true;
    newScreen = screen;
    fade.IsActive = true;
    fade.Alpha = 0.0f;
    fade.Increase = true;
    fade.activateValue = 1.0f;
    this.inputManager = inputManager;
}
```

the problem may extend to the fade animation class too? but I figured I would start with this. When the error occurs, animation count is 1, and imageNumber is also 1.

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, so if your count is 1, your image number is trying access an index that's out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment `imageNumber` and have a guard for when it exceeds the max, but nowhere do you reset it back to `0` again.

Change:

```
if (imageNumber >= animation.Count - 1 || inputManager.KeyPressed(Keys.Enter))
{                    
    ScreenManager.Instance.AddScreen(new TitleScreen(), inputManager);
}
```

...to:

```
if (imageNumber >= animation.Count - 1 || inputManager.KeyPressed(Keys.Enter))
{                    
    ScreenManager.Instance.AddScreen(new TitleScreen(), inputManager);
    imageNumber = 0;  // reset the sequence
}
```

...in your `Update()` method.

Comment: Thank you! This brought on a new set of problems, but it isn't THAT error, which was giving me trouble!

Comment: @Islands OK. You can always post that as a _new question_ if you like.  _Accept_ this on as the answer if you think it is so.  Wishing you a good weekend